# $this when not in object context in constants.php

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I try to use `define('LANG', $this->uri->rsegment(2));` in `constants.php`, I got this error:

`Using $this when not in object context in constants.php`.

I have no clue why. I'm quite new with **codeIgniter** and I want to define a constant that will take the language from the URI. I have already done something similar using `REQUEST_URI`, but with `uri->segment`; that will be much easier.

Comment: Do you know what `$this` even is? It might help you figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Have you tried `$CI =& get_instance(); $CI->uri->rsegment(2);`?

Comment: Yeah I tried `$CI` and it doesn't work... :s `$This` is used to call loaded function of codeIgniter.

Comment: @arxanas `=&`? What is this, PHP4?

Comment: @DaveRandom I dunno, it's convention among CodeIgniter to do that, or so I gather.

Comment: @arxanas Indeed it does seem to be, even the CI docs tell you to do it. It doesn't break anything but it is completely pointless in PHP5, all object variables are just pointers, so if you create a copy of it it doesn't matter because even a copy of the pointer still points to the same underlying object

Comment: Why are you trying to define a constant when it's not a constant? You should be defining a variable somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way codeigniter is architectured, you cannot use  `$this` in config.php, because all the framework resources are not loaded by the time constant.php is loaded.

In order to do what you need to, you should do the following:

Create a new custom config file, say app_config.php (you can call it whatever you want)

Add this code to app_config file:

```
$ci = &get_instance();
define('LANG', $ci->uri->rsegment(2));
```

Place this file in config folder (same folder where config.php is)

In autoload.php, add this config file's name to be autoloaded as:

```
/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Auto-load Config files
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| Prototype:
|
|   $autoload['config'] = array('config1', 'config2');
|
| NOTE: This item is intended for use ONLY if you have created custom
| config files.  Otherwise, leave it blank.
|
*/

$autoload['config'] = array('app_config');
```

Now you will be able to access the constant LANG across the application..

Comment: It seems right, but I got another error...`Undefined property: CI_Config::$uri`

Comment: Use this code in app_config:

 `$ci = &get_instance();
 define('LANG', $ci->uri->rsegment(2));`

I have updated the answer accordingly

Comment: Yeah it's working! But I need also to add `$config['LANG']` like this: `$config['LANG'] = define('LANG', $ci->uri->rsegment(2));`

Comment: "Note: If you do create your own config files use the same format as the primary one, storing your items in an array called $config. CodeIgniter will intelligently manage these files so there will be no conflict even though the array has the same name (assuming an array index is not named the same as another)." from the user guide ([http://codeigniter.com/user_guide//libraries/config.html])

Comment: The edit you did to your comment is wrong. It should be `$config['LANG'] = $ci->uri->rsegment(2);`.